# Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: sqlite, spring-boot, gradle

Estou tentando configurar um acesso da minha aplicação para um banco de dados SQLite com utilização do arquivo `application.properties` do Spring Boot, mas não esta reconhecendo o driver. Como posso proceder para que ao inicializar com o Gradle a aplicação reconheça o driver?

**build.grade**:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.cryptotechnologies'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.10.1')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:smart-payments-db.db
```

**Log**:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:232) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:184) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:56) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Acabei de subir um serviço spring-boot com SQLite. Na verdade, adicionei um banco embarcado para fazer uma camada de aceleração, que a consulta ao banco real é muito pesada, podendo portanto dar mais disponibilidade. Voltando do almoço eu posto como configurar corretamente

Comment: Me enganei, eu registrei o `DataSource` com sucesso, sem nem precisar citar o `Driver`